# Mysql sum of same varchar

Tags: mysql, sum, varchar

I have a database like this:

```
ID     Ages   
 1    30-40  
 2    70-80  
 3    50-60  
 4    30-40
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
Total   Ages 
 2     30-40
 1     70-80
 1     50-60
```

I actually want to sum same age groups of people in the db

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Ages, Count(*) as Total
FROM your-table
GROUP BY Ages
```